# Spring Batch ItemReader list processed only once

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to create a Spring Batch job using a `ListItemReader<String>`, `ItemProcessor<String, String>` and `ItemWriter<String>`.

The XML looks like the following,

```
<job id="sourceJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step1" next="step2">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="svnSourceItemReader" 
                processor="metadataItemProcessor" 
                writer="metadataItemWriter" 
                commit-interval="1" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
    <step id="step2">
        <tasklet ref="lastRevisionLoggerTasklet"></tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="svnSourceItemReader" 
        class="com.example.repository.batch.SvnSourceItemReader" 
        scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <list>
            <value>doc1.xkbml</value>
            <value>doc2.xkbml</value>
            <value>doc3.xkbml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="metadataItemProcessor" 
        class="com.example.repository.batch.MetadataItemProcessor" 
        scope="prototype" />

<bean id="metadataItemWriter" 
        class="com.example.repository.batch.MetadataItemWriter" 
        scope="prototype" />
```

The reader, processor and writer are vanilla,

```
public class SvnSourceItemReader extends ListItemReader<String> {

    public SvnSourceItemReader(List<String> list) {
        super(list);
        System.out.println("Reading data list " + list);
    }

    @Override
    public String read() {
        String out = (String) super.read();
        System.out.println("Reading data " + out);
        return out;
    }

}

public class MetadataItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String process(String i) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Processing " + i + " : documentId " + documentId);
        return i;
    }

}

public class MetadataItemWriter implements ItemWriter<String> {

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends String> list) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Writing " + list);
    }

}
```

The job is started like this, but on a schedule of every 10 seconds.

```
long nanoBits = System.nanoTime() % 1000000L;
if (nanoBits < 0) {
    nanoBits *= -1;
}
String dateParam = new Date().toString() + System.currentTimeMillis() 
        + "." + nanoBits;
param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", dateParam)
        .toJobParameters();
JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
```

When the application starts, I see it read, process and write each of the three items in the list passed to the reader.

```
Reading data doc1.xkbml
Processing doc1.xkbml : documentId doc1
Writing [doc1.xkbml]
Reading data doc2.xkbml
Processing doc2.xkbml : documentId doc2
Writing [doc2.xkbml]
Reading data doc3.xkbml
Processing doc3.xkbml : documentId doc3
Writing [doc3.xkbml]
```

Because this `sourceJob` is on a scheduled timer, every 10 seconds I expected to see that list processed, but instead I see on all subsequent runs.

```
Reading data null
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm new to Spring Batch and just can't get my hands around the issue.

Thanks /w

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that you marked your reader as `scope="prototype"`. It should be `scope="step"`.

In Spring-batch there are only two scopes: `singleton` (the default) and `step`.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/StepScope.html):

> **StepScope**: 
> Scope for step context. Objects in this scope use the
>   Spring container as an object factory, so there is only one instance
>   of such a bean per executing step. All objects in this scope are
>    (no need to decorate the bean definitions).

and

> Using a scope of Step is required in order to use late binding since
>   the bean cannot actually be instantiated until the Step starts, which
>   allows the attributes to be found.

During the Spring context startup look at your log and you will see this line:

> INFO: Done executing SQL script from class path resource
>   [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql] in 9 ms.
>  
>   Reading data list [doc1.xkbml, doc2.xkbml, doc3.xkbml]

as you can see your reader has already been created and managed as a singleton; dynamic beans in spring-batch context should be managed with the special `step` scope so that Spring will create a fresh copy of the bean every time a step is executed.

In your reader, `ListItemReader.read()` is written as:

```
public T read() {
  if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    return list.remove(0);
  }
  return null;
}
```

In each read items are removed from original list! The reader is constructed once and, on second job execution, the list is empty!

Comment: Great. Can we use ListItemReader in multi-threaded step to process items in list concurrently ? Will restart work for it ?

Comment: Nope. ListItemReader is not restartable because it doesn't support ItemStrem; this class (from javadoc) is **'Useful for testing'**

Answer (score 4):

Just an additional information: you can also use JavaConfig instead of the xml config file, and annotate the reader bean declaration with @StepConfig.

ex:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyConfig {
...

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<HeadingBreakevenAssociation> readerHeadingBreakevenAssociationList(){
         ItemReader<Person> itemReader = new ListItemReader<Person>(myList);

          return itemReader;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you pass myList to readerHeadingBreakevenAssociationList?