# How to pass List to Spring Batch ItemReader via REST call

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-batch

I'm working on a REST method that will perform a job using Spring Batch.

I have a simple job defined,

```
<job id="myIndexJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="myIndexItemReader" processor="myIndexItemProcessor" writer="myIndexItemWriter" commit-interval="1" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

This job mimics a question I posted earlier,

[Spring Batch ItemReader list processed only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519645/spring-batch-itemreader-list-processed-only-once)

But this time, instead of executing the job on a schedule, I want to manually execute it via a REST call.

The problem I'm having is passing a `List` to the `myIndexItemReader`. My REST call will generate a `List` based on some query string. The previous question I posted got it's `List` handed to it via the spring bean in the XML each time the step ran.

I'd like to do something like this,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/{regex}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void run(@PathVariable String regex) {

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("something");

    long nanoBits = System.nanoTime() % 1000000L;
    if (nanoBits < 0) {
        nanoBits *= -1;
    }
    String dateParam = new Date().toString() + System.currentTimeMillis() 
            + "." + nanoBits;
    JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("date", dateParam)
            .toJobParameters();
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);

}
```

but I just don't know how to pass `myList` to the `myIndexItemReader`.

As of now I can do this by creating a `RepeatTemplate` and calling `iterate` on a callback, but the job `chunk` seems more clean.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions? Thanks /w

Comment: Could you pass the query string to the batch job as a job parameter and then have the batch job reader use the query to create the list?

Comment: Are queries ever the same between job calls or can be different?

Comment: @bellabax they can be the same or different but this call probably would be very infrequent.

Comment: @FGreg I wasn't thinking about the job parameters. Is that easily accessible from the reader? I've not read about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took an alternate approach and stored information in a database table based on the REST criteria. Then the `ItemReader` read the table and cleared it after each run.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass queries as job parameters, but you have to be carefully because string job parameter has a finite lenght (250) (look [Metadata schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html)).
If this can be a limit you can precompile a property file like that:

**queries.properties**

```
query1=<query string 1>
query2=<query string 2>
query3=<query string 3>
queryn=<query string n>
```

As job parameters you can pass:

```
queriesIdsCount (integer): number of queries (0..n)
queryId0 (string): identifier of query in queries.properties file (ex: query2)
queryId1 (string): (ex. query3)
queryIdn (string): (ex. query1)
```

and so on so you can select queries from your list.
With a [`Tasklet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html) or a usual Reader/Process/Writer (as first step) you can process your job parameters and create `List<>` using REST.
Job parameters are available using spEL look about [late-binding](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#late-binding).

I hope I was clear, English is not my native language.